# How to set text from encapsulated variable

Tags: java, getter-setter, encapsulation

I have placed this code in a new class

```
public class Monster {
private String name;
private int health, mana, attack;

public void setName(String name) {this.name=name;}
public void setHealth(int health) {this.health=health;}
public void setMana(int mana){this.mana=mana;}
public void setAttack(int attack){this.attack=attack;}

public String getName() {return name;}
public int getHealth() {return health;}
public int getMana() {return mana;}
public int getAttack(){return attack;}

public Monster(String name, int health, int mana, int attack) {
}
```

and want to use it in a different activity. I made sure to import the class in the activity and have written these codes:

```
Monster vampire = new Monster("Vampire", 2000, 300, 25);
```

I want to set text view according to what is written so I wrote:

```
    monsterName.setText(String.valueOf(vampire.getName()));
monsterHP.setText(String.valueOf(vampire.getHealth()));
monsterMP.setText(String.valueOf(vampire.getMana()));
```

but when I run the application, text view writes 'null' and monsterHP and monsterMP writes '0'. How do I set the text according to the class?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `vampire` instead of using `ogre` ? Where do you initialize this instance of `Monster` class ? Furthermore, from the code you have shared is not clear which are the constructor(s)of `Monster` class. If you have also a parameter-less constructor apart from the one you use for the instance you create and assign its reference to `vampire`, it starts to make sense what might have been done. If that's the case, I suspect that you have something like this `Monster ogre = new Monster()`. If that's true, then its clear what is going on and I will elaborate more on that.

Comment: You need to show the `Monster` constructor in your question.

Comment: @Christos yes, I also have `Monster ogre=new Monster()` and 5 more of that with different names. I placed the constructor inside the Monster class.

Comment: @Ack You can check my answer that explains why you see that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom constructor is not properly initialized.
When call `Monster vampire = new Monster("Vampire", 2000, 300, 25);` no values are set, so obvious `null:string` and `0:numbers` returns (java default initializers).

Adapt with:

```
public Monster(String name, int health, int mana, int attack) {
this.name = name;
this.health = health;
this.mana = mana;
this.attack = atack;
}
```